# How To use Website with Remote Control in Android

Tags: android, web

I want open my webite in android settopbox
model :  Q1 Himedia

but i can't select any item from website ?
Now How I can for this Problem??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not idea much but below link help you

http://web.airdroid.com/

http://thecodepost.in/internet/remote-control-android-device-anywhere

Comment: I installed airDroid but not soloved it

Comment: @FarzadSarsify : Right my question please

Comment: Nirav Ranpara : No I use airDroid but not soloved.. and work with firefox and chrome but not soloved with remote Control because objects and links not selected. Finally use Default Broweser QI Himedia.this Browser Perfectly works with Remots